# cakephp stop ajax submit

Tags: ajax, cakephp, submit

Is there a way to stop cakephp ajax submit to stop the submission in case the user has not entered required details and click the submit button.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the $ajax->submit '**create**' options, calling user javascript function foo().
Inside the foo() function I have **Event.stop('submitButtonId');** where **submitButtonId** is the submit button id.

The Event.stop() stops the event from bubbling up, and thus prevented the ajax submission.